# How can I call superclass method with data from subclass?

Tags: python, inheritance, polymorphism, python-3.5

I'm parsing data from an XML file and I need to convert some of it to integers - when setting them to attributes of the B class. Since I have multiple subclasses, I'm trying to write the code once in the superclass instead of having to write it in each subclass.

```
class A:

  def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    if isinstance(__class__.__dict__[name], int):
      self.__dict__[name] = int(value)

class B(A):

  val = int()

  def __init__(self, val):
    self.val = val


b = B("4")
print(type(b.val))
```

My problem is that `__class__` and `self` refer to the superclass. I need the ones from the subclasses. Any ideas?

---

I'm not sure if I explain my problem very well, so here is the code if I had to do it only for one class:

```
class A:
  val = int()

  def __init__(self, val1): #val1 is a string
    self.val = val1

  def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    if isinstance(A.__dict__[name], int):
      self.__dict__[name] = int(value)

b = A("4")
print(type(b.val)) #prints <class 'int'>
```

Comment: There appears to be no point in creating the *class* attribute `val`. That's not a declaration for an instance attribute.

Comment: It's a way to keep what type I want for the instance attribute with the same name.

Comment: A comment would do that just as well.

Comment: `self` refers to the *object*, not any particular class.

Comment: I use the class attribute for comparison here: isinstance(__class__.__dict__[name], int)

Comment: But *why*? Are you trying to implement run-time type checking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `classmethod` to get the derived class and pass the known self as a parameter

```
class A:

  def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    self._setter(self, name, value)

  @classmethod
  def _setter(cls, self, name, value):
      if isinstance(getattr(cls, name), int):
         self.__dict__[name] = int(value)

class B(A):

  val = int()

  def __init__(self, val):
    self.val = val


b = B("4")
print(type(b.val), b.val)
```

Instead of assigning a variable and using its type, you could just assign the type itself in the class. I've put it all in a dict called `schema` because that seems to document better what is going on to me.

```
class A:

  schema = {}

  def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    self._setter(self, name, value)

  @classmethod
  def _setter(cls, self, name, value):
      if name in cls.schema:
          value = cls.schema[name](value)
      self.__dict__[name] = value

class B(A):

  schema = {"val":int}

  def __init__(self, val):
      self.val = val

b = B("4")
print(type(b.val), b.val)
```